PHP y MYSQL, ingresar datos de forma dinámica
Es mi primer consulta en esta pagina. Estoy armando un sistema de producción con PHP y MySQL, tengo en la BD una tabla con los insumos y otra con los productos, los productos requieren insumos.
La inserción a la base de datos la tengo con solo dos insumo por producto, pero esto no es real porque hay productos que llevan mas insumo el tema que no se como hacerlo dinámico, paso parte del código
function insertarProducto ($nombre_producto,$insumo_necesario,$insumo_id,
$insumo_cantidad_usada,$insumo_necesario_2,$insumo_id_2,$insumo_cantidad_usada_2,) 

Esta es otra parte del código
$consulta = "INSERT INTO producto (producto_nombre,insumo_nombre,insumo_id,
stock_usado,insumo_nombre_2, insumo_id_2,stock_usado_2) 
VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 
$stmt = $base->prepare($consulta); 

$stmt->execute([$nombre_producto,$insumo_necesario,$insumo_id,
$insumo_cantidad_usada,$insumo_necesario_2,$insumo_id_2,$insumo_cantidad_usada_2]);


No he comprendido bien a que te refieres con "dinámico". Puedes expresar un poco mejor eso? No uses tecnicismos, pregunta como lo harías a un colega

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Tengo miedo de preguntar... hay una columna insumo por cada insumo que tiene algo?? o sea, esa base de datos no esta normalizada??? ç

@OCHOA pienso que "dinámico" se refiera al numero de campos en la tabla.

Necesitas nos mostrar todos los campos de la tabla "producto" en la BD

Las base de datos MySQL son bases de datos de tipo "relacional". Esto es precisamente lo que necesitas para lo que quieres conseguir.
Las bases de datos relacionales sirven para relacionar distintos datos entre si, en tu caso productos con insumos.
Normalmente esto se hace con "llaves primarias" y "llaves foráneas", que se utilizan para "crear" una relación entre un elemento y otro.
Esto normalmente se hace mediante 2 o 3 tablas dependiendo de si la relación es uno a uno, uno a muchos, muchos amuchos, etc.
Por ejemplo, si en tu caso el producto puede tener varios insumos, pero esos insumos solo van a pertenecer a un producto, la relación seria Producto (uno) insumos (muchos).
Una manera de organizar las tablas para este ejemplo sería:
Tabla Productos:
- id
- nombre
- precio
- etc

Tabla Insumos:
- id
- producto_id
- nombre_insumo
- etc

*Los nombres de los campos me los he inventado para el ejemplo, tendrás que ver tu que poner según tus necesidades.
Como ves, en la tabla de insumos, tenemos una columna "producto_id" el cual nos va a servir para obtener todos los insumos de un producto en concreto.
Ejemplo con "datos inventados":
Productos:
- id: 1 - nombre: Pantalón - precio: 20€
- id: 2 - nombre: Camiseta - precio: 10€

Insumos:
- id: 1 - producto_id: 1 - nombre: insumo_1_pantalon
- id: 2 - producto_id: 2 - nombre: insumo_1_camiseta
- id: 3 - producto_id: 1 - nombre: insumo_2_pantalon
- id: 4 - producto_id: 1 - nombre: insumo_3_pantalon

Con ese ejemplo, a la hora de realizar las consultas a nuestra base de datos, si por ejemplo quisiesemos obtener los insumos del producto con id 1 podriamos hacer la siguiente consulta
SELECT * FROM insumos WHERE producto_id = 1

Esto nos devolvería los registros con id 1,3 y 4 del ejemplo.
A la hora de insertar insumos a la base de datos, bastará con que indiques en el insert a que producto pertenece mediante el producto_id.
Te recomiendo que busques información acerca de las relaciones en MYSQL
Tienes toda la documentación de mysql en: https://dev.mysql.com/

Agrega en algun lado que con urgencia OP estudie normalizacion de bases de datos.. todo su problema radica en no saber hacer eso...

Entiendo que supongas la relación 1 a muchos por simplificar tu solución, pero es muy probable que un insumo pueda ser usado en varios productos. Salvo que te lo especifiquen claramente, yo no lo daría por hecho. También ten en cuenta que una FK y una relación no es exactamente lo mismo. Por lo demás, buena respuesta, gracias por tu aportación.
